# Doxygen not working on Public block(s) after Private block in Class

Tags: c++, class, private, doxygen, public

How do I tell Doxygen to document public sections after a private section in a (C++) class?

E.g.

```
class Brg {

public:

    //! this function will be documented
    void documentedFunction1()

 private:

    void irrelevantFunction()

 public:


    //! this function will _not_ be documented
    void undocumentedFunction1()
};
```

Even without the first public section, the second public section is still undocumented.

**doxylog.txt reports:**

> Warning: documented function `Brg:: undocumentedFunction1' was not declared or defined

```
# Doxyfile 1.5.2
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "Blah"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./gen_docs/
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = 
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
DETAILS_AT_TOP         = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_DIRECTORIES       = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = doxylog.txt
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = . \
             ..\Code
IMAGE_PATH         = .
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.cpp \
                         *.cc \
                         *.h \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.txt
EXAMPLE_PATH           = . \
             ..\Code \
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *.lua \
                         *.h
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_ALIGN_MEMBERS     = YES
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = YES
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = YES
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = amsmath
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4wide
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_SCHEMA             = 
XML_DTD                = 
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor   
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration::additions related to external references   
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = ../ExternalModule/ExternalModule.tag=../../../ExternalModule/Docs/html
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = Modulename.tag
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool   
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
DOT_PATH               = 
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration::additions related to the search engine   
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
```

Comment: Can you post the doxygen configuration file that you are using? Doxygen normally will document both functions.

Comment: I hope you have the semi-colons ; after the member function declarations.

Comment: Hah, yes, in the actual code there are semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code sample above (with added semi-colons) and provided doxygen configuration file, both of the functions are documented with Doxygen 1.5.2 (the authors version based on the configuration file) and Doxygen 1.7.6.1 (latest).

The Doxygen configuration file appears to reference an external tag file as well as additional directories. Its possible there is some interaction with one of those files that would affect doxygen's behavior in this case, however there isn't enough information in the test case to investigate further.